# How to use const int in _Static_assert?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

Preamble: I want to statically check amount of struct members in **C program**, so I created two macros, each of them creates constant int storing `__LINE__` into variable:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define BEGIN(log) const int __##log##_begin = __LINE__;
 #define END(log) const int __##log##_end = __LINE__;
 BEGIN(TEST);
 struct TEST {
    int t1;
    int t2;
    float t3;
    int t4;
    int t5;
    int t6;
 };
 END(TEST)

 main()
 {
    static_assert(__TEST_end - __TEST_begin  == 6 + 3, "not_equal");
 }
```

When I use C++ compiler with -std=c++11 option (c++ test.cpp -std=c++11), it works fine, but the same code (with replacement of static_assert to _Static_assert) doesn't work in C(gcc version 4.8.4) with a strange error as this expression could be evaluated at a compile time:

> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:18:17: error: expression in static
>   assertion is not constant   _Static_assert(__TEST_end - __TEST_begin 
>   == 6 + 4, "not_equal");

How can I fix this error or achieve the original goal in C?

Comment: Just a tip: If you include assert.h, you can use the macro `static_assert` which expands to the C keyword `_Static_assert`. Useful for C++ compatibility.

Comment: @NaCl: when I declare variables as `constexpr`, compilator produces more errors.

Comment: @Scipio: `constexpr` is a C++11 keyword, and won't work in C11. On an unrelated note, you might want to look at DMS, a tool made by fellow StackOverflow user [Ira Baxter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C a variable even if defined with const is not a constant expression. _Static_assert requires its first parameter to be a constant expression. Therefore the same thing that can be done in C++ cannot be done in C.

You can do a runtime check instead; use assert.

Note that this method won't guard you against a programmer typing out two members in the same line or using multiple single line declarations of the same type, or adding an empty line (or a comment). Instead of forcing a programmer to follow a string coding pattern, just so that this assert will catch the error, it is less error prone to simply require the programmer to define a correct number of members. It is strictly better, because you can make the an undetectable error either way, but at least doesn't have to worry about the strict coding pattern.

Comment: I can't use assert as this code is executed on embedded hardware. These structs (there are a few dozens of them) are used in logging code, which describes structs' members in a c-string(like this one for the example above "llflll"). Errors in such descriptions could be discovered only after some manual actions which is IMO way worse than static checks and restricted coding pattern. Anyway, if it's really impossible to perform static checks of struct's member count, I'll accept your answer as most helpful.

Comment: @Scipio Actually it is relatively easy. Just include another step when building the code. Parse the source code with a custom program that counts the members and outputs the information to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your issue would be to use an anonymous enumeration. Instead of:

```
#define BEGIN(log) const int __##log##_begin = __LINE__
#define END(log) const int __##log##_end = __LINE__
```

Do:

```
#define BEGIN(log) enum { __##log##_begin = __LINE__ }
#define END(log) enum { __##log##_end = __LINE__ }
```

This is allowed in C11 since, unlike a `const int` (or even `static const int`) variable, an enumeration constant *is* defined to be an integral constant expression.

(As an aside, I omitted the terminal semicolon from my version of your `BEGIN()`/`END()` macros. In my opinion, declaration macros should not include a terminal semicolon, that should be provided by the macro user, so the macro behaves more like a non-macro C declaration.)